# I need help with independent clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses, subordinate-clauses, dependent-clause

I got a bit confused about independent clauses,so I decided to ask ChatGpt, which has given me three different answers for the same sentence I think he is getting too old, suffering from Alzheimer's disease.

The sentence is:

> I bring a natural positivity and a can-do attitude, allowing me to effectively solve challenging problems even under pressure.

Here are my questions about that :

First of all "allowing me to effectively solve challenging problems even under" **is that a gerund clause functions as an adjective for the main clause describe it**

**Now regarding the clause I have two possible analyses**

The first one is that:

- "allowing me to effectively"  is a gerund phrase that acts as a
  subject.
- "solve" is the main verb.
- "challenging problems" is the direct object.
- "even under pressure" is a prepositional phrase that acts as an
  adverb

The second one would be: .

- "allowing me"  is a gerund phrase to start the caluse
- "to effectively solve" is an infinitive phrase
- "challenging problems" is the direct object to solve
- "even under pressure" is a prepositional phrase that acts as an
  adverb

Does anyone have a clue which analysis is right and why?

Comment: Have you asked yourself the question "what is doing the allowing?"?

Comment: I'd say *...allowing me to effectively solve challenging problems even under pressure* is a participial clause, same as, for example *...making me a strong candidate*. In both cases, they "adverbially" modify the primary assertion ***I bring [my assets]***. But further breakdown *within* that clause gives ***allowing*** as the "main verb".

Comment: @Tuffy it introduces the clause

Comment: @FumbleFingers  which analysis do you think works

Comment: AI dishes up what it finds and has no way of knowing what is correct or incorrect without further "training" via crowd-sourced "corrections". All questions that cite AI as an authority should be immediately closed.

Comment: @ Fumble Fingers Exactly.  This was my (in the event) not very good way of dropping a hint about how to think about answering the question.

Comment: I think ***solve*** can't be an important verb in the context of further breakdown of the participial clause, simply because *structurally speaking*, there needn't even be ***any*** verb there. It could have been *...allowing **an easy hiring decision** [to be made by the addressee]*. If you don't even *need* a verb, any verb that *does* exist can't be that central to the breakdown.

Comment: The wording is okay, but a string of cliches in an objective or career statement within a resume or cover letter. Saying I am this or that is strictly a claim. A resume makes a stronger case when it shows the reader how you have a natural positivity (can-do attitude is the same thing) that allows you to [effectively] solve challenging problems under pressure.

Comment: @YosefBaskin It may be cliche, but since everyone else does it, you have to do it to be competitive. Omitting self-praise may raise questions about why you aren't extolling your virtues. OTOH, resume readers probably gloss over boilerplate like this.

Comment: When I asked ChatGPT whether it is better in an Android app to leave a file open, or open and close it, when I want to append a small amout of data every 5 seconds, it told me it is a poor use of system resources to keep opening and closing, and a poor use of system resources to leave it open. ChatGPT has access to so many resources that it can be confused. It lacks judgement.

Answer (score 1):

> *I bring a natural positivity and a can-do attitude,* [*allowing me to*
> *effectively solve challenging problems even under pressure*].

The bracketed constituent is a subordinate gerund-participial clause (your gerund clause), but it doesn't function as a modifier (your 'adjective'); rather, it functions as an adjunct indicating a resultative or subsequent situation. Incidentally, adjective is a word class (POS), not a function.

Like most non-finite clauses, the subordinate clause doesn't have an overt subject, though we *understand* it to be "a natural positivity and a can-do attitude".

Within the subordinate clause, "me" is the object of "allowing", and the infinitival clause is complement of "allowing". The adverb phrase "even under pressure" functions as an adjunct in clause structure, i.e. a modifier in the infinitival clause.

As you say, "challenging problems" is the object of "solving".

Comment: if allowing is the main verb but is that true with "are" omitted?  like so 
**are allowing me to  effectively solve etc ..**
I did suppose an adjective clause because I modify it so  **"I bring a natural positivity and a can-do attitude, [which are allowing me to effectively solve challenging problems even under pressure]** It makes sense
can verbs have complements?  I only know there are a subject  complement, an object complement

Comment: @MohannadBakbouk No: it's not some kind of relative clause. Note that supplementary (non-defining) relatives are not modifiers, Complements, such as subject and object ones, are complements of verbs.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Grammar frameworks and terms vary. Proceed at your own risk . . .</sub>

*Allowing me to effectively solve challenging problems even under pressure* can be imagined as a “reduced sentence relative clause” wherein:

1. *allowing* is reduced from *which allows* — in the manner that relative clauses are reduced: by removing the relative pronoun (*which*) and changing the verb (*allows*) to a participle (*allowing*):

> *I bring a natural positivity and a can-do attitude, **which allows** me to effectively solve challenging problems even under pressure.*
>
> *I bring a natural positivity and a can-do attitude, **allowing** me to effectively solve challenging problems even under pressure.*

2. Your relative clause is a **sentence** relative clause. Grammarian and English professor Richard Nordquist describes sentence relative clauses like this:

> Sentence relative clauses refer back to the whole clause or sentence,
> not just to one noun. 
>  <sub>Source: [ThoughtCo — Relative Clause
> Definition and Examples in
> English](https://www.thoughtco.com/relative-clause-grammar-1692042)</sub>